# Can one use Windows 10 completely by command line?

Tags: windows-10

I have been wondered if one can use Windows 10 completely without mouse? For example, if I see some bug in software, I can write a script to repeat it. Is there a way to move mouse cursor and push and release mouse buttons by command line?

Comment: *Use Windows 10...by command line* Or keyboard? Which do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can I control the mouse from a command line?

[nircmd](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/) from [nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) can be used to control the mouse. All the following commands can be called from a batch script.

The general form of the command will be `nircmd` followed by one of the following commands:

> `setcursor [X] [Y]`
>
> Set the position of mouse cursor. The [X] and [Y] parameters specifies the desired cursor position.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> setcursor 100 50
> ```

Source [setcursor](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/setcursor.html)

> `movecursor [X] [Y]`
>
> move the mouse cursor. The [X] and [Y] parameters specifies the number of pixels to move.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> movecursor 10 10
> ```

Source [movecursor](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/movecursor.html)

> > `sendmouse [right | left | middle] [down | up | click | dblclick]`
> >
> > `sendmouse [move] [x] [y]`
> >
> > `sendmouse [wheel] [Wheel Value]`
> >
> > Sends the specified mouse event to the system. The operating system will behave exactly as the user really made the specified mouse
> >     action.
>
> Examples:
>
> - Sent a right click (For most applications, a context menu is opened):
>
>   ```
>   sendmouse right click
>   ```
> - Sent a double-click with the left mouse button:
>
>   ```
>   sendmouse left dblclick
>   ```
> - Press the left mouse button, move the mouse cursor 20 pixels left and 30 pixels down, and then release the button:
>
>   ```
>   sendmouse left down
>   sendmouse move -30 20
>   sendmouse left up
>   ```
> - Scroll the mouse wheel 10 units in standard wheel mouse. (On standard wheel mouse, the wheel value should be a multiple of 120).
>
>   ```
>   sendmouse wheel 1200
>   ```

Source [sendmouse](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/sendmouse.html)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) in any way, I am just an end user of their software.

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.